# type error collection() method error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to run a node program but I get type error db.collection not defined please don't make this question duplicate because I have read all the answers that didn't solve my problem. I have a config.js which holds my dbconnect method which is

```
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
require('dotenv').config();
function connectdb()
{
    //console.log(process.env.url);
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>
    {
        MongoClient.connect(process.env.url,function(err, db) {
                if (err){
                        reject("database connection error");
                         }
                         else
                         {
                            resolve(db);
                         }
                        });
    });
}

exports.connectdb=connectdb;
```

Then I have a routes.js where

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let connectdb=require("H:/Student/src/config/config.js").connectdb;
let student=require("H:/Student/src/services/studentservice.js").student;
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get("/",async function (req, res) {
try{
        let a1= await connectdb();
        let result=await student(a1);
        res.send(result);
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
   });
};
```

Then I have a service which gets results from collection

```
require('dotenv').config();
function student(db)
{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>
    {
     db.collection(process.env.collection).find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err)
    {
    reject("database query error");
    }
    else
    {
        resolve(result);
    }
});
    });
}
exports.student=student;
```

Then I have main index.js file

```
let express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config();
let bodyParser =require("body-parser");
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let app = express();
require("./src/routes/user.js")(app);
app.listen(3000,() => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

I get the typeError:db.collection is not defined but when console log I can see that database object is passed. I am using mongodb 2.2.3.

Comment: In witch file is the error?

Comment: its in the student function says db.collection is not defined

Comment: its in the student function says db.collection is not defined?@nikola andreev

Comment: Try to update mongoDb version to newer. I have seen similar issues with older versions like yours.

Comment: ya it worked thanks@nikola andreev